# MySQL database connection for Play Framework

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, web-applications, playframework

I'm using Intellij IDEA for developing Play Scala Applications, I wanted to connect to MySQL database, Intellij has an inbuilt option of connection to MySQL. I connected through it and it showed a successful connection.

I was wondering if I have to connect it manually as well in the application.conf

Thanks

Comment: Yes you do. Have you looked at this page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDatabase

Comment: Yes I have, but I thought once I included it in IDEA, I don't have to do it again. Thanks for the information.